# In which case does TaskCompletionSource.SetResult() run the continuation synchronously?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

Initially I thought that all continuations are executed on the threadpool (given a default synchronization context). This however doesn't seem to be the case when I use a `TaskCompletionSource`.

My code looks something like this:

```
Task<int> Foo() {
  _tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
  return _tcs.Task;
}

async void Bar() {
  Console.WriteLine(Thread.Current.ManagedThreadId);
  Console.WriteLine($"{Thread.Current.ManagedThreadId} - {await Foo()}");
}
```

`Bar` gets called on a specific thread and the `TaskCompletionSource` stays unset for some time, meaning the returned tasks `IsComplete = false`. Then after some time, the same thread would proceed to call `_tcs.SetResult(x)`, which by my understanding should run the continuation on the threadpool.

But what I observed in my application is that the thread running the continuation is in fact still the same thread, as if the continuation was invoked synchronously right as `SetResult` is called.

I even tried setting a breakpoint on the `SetResult` and stepping over it (and having a breakpoint in the continuation), which in turn actually goes on to call the continuation synchronously.

**When exactly does `SetResult()` immediately call the continuation synchronously?**

Comment: It would help if you'd provide a [mcve] rather than *half* of it, so we could experiment with it ourselves...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`SetResult` *usually* runs continuations from TCS synchronously. There main exception to this is if you **explicitly** pass in the `TaskContinuationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously` flag when creating the TCS (new in .NET 4.6). The other scenario when it runs things asynchronously is if it thinks the current thread is doomed.

This is quite important, because if you're not careful you can end up having calling code take control of a thread that was meant to be doing other work (like: dealing with socket IO).

Comment: BTW: What happens when you call `SetResult()` on a thread that isn't the original pre-await caller? Shouldn't the continuation try to get to the original-caller thread because of default `ConfigureAwait(...)`?

Comment: @Petrroll if there was no `SyncronisationContext.Current` when the function was called it will have no original thread to go to.

Comment: And if it there was some explicit SyncContext?

Comment: AFAIK if there is explicit `SynchronizationContext` and it is captured all continuations should be passed to it (unless the task was completed when you await it). Is this correct?

Comment: @JakubArnold yes, the sync-context confuses matters somewhat, but it is somewhat vague and confused, frankly. Which is a shame, because avoiding threads being stolen is kind of important! Besides, the caller can always `ConfugureAwait(false)` etc

Comment: Thanks Marc, that's a great explanation.  "avoiding threads being stolen is kind of important".  I've just ran into this myself.  I can't understand why synchronous is the default?  It seems very dangerous, as you have no idea whether the continuation will ever complete, and there's no hint from the signature of SetResult that you are giving up your thread when you call it.  I don't understand why this hasn't caused problems for me before now, and why it doesn't cause lots of problems for everyone.  (In my case it caused a deadlock by stealing the executing thread)

Answer (score 21):

> Initially I thought that all continuations are executed on the threadpool (given a default synchronization context). This however doesn't seem to be the case when I use a TaskCompletionSource.

Actually, when using `await`, most continuations are executed synchronously.

Marc's answer is great; I just wanted to go into a bit more detail...

`TaskCompletionSource<T>` by default will operate synchronously when `Set*` is called. `Set*` will complete the task *and* issue the continuations in a single method call. (This means that calling `Set*` while holding a lock is a recipe for deadlocks.)

I use the weird phrase "issue the continuations" there because it may or may not actually execute them; more on that later.

The `TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously` flag will tell `TaskCompletionSource<T>` to issue the continuations asynchronously. This breaks apart the completing of the task (which is still done immediately by `Set*`) from the issuing of the continuations (which is only triggered by the `Set*` call). So with `RunContinuationsAsynchronously`, a `Set*` call will only complete the task; it will not execute the continuations synchronously. (This means that calling `Set*` while holding a lock is safe.)

But back to the default case, which issues the continuations synchronously.

Each continuation *also* has a flag; by default a continuation is executed *asynchronously*, but it can be made synchronous by `TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously`. (Note that [`await` *does* use this flag](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/dont-block-in-asynchronous-code.html) - link is to my blog; technically this is an implementation detail and not officially documented).

However, even if `ExecuteSynchronously` is specified, there are [a number of situations where the continuation is not executed synchronously](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/02/07/when-executesynchronously-doesnt-execute-synchronously/):

- If there is a `TaskScheduler` associated with the continuation, that scheduler is given the option of rejecting the current thread, in which case the task is *queued* to that `TaskScheduler` instead of executing synchronously.
- If the current thread is being aborted, then the task is queued elsewhere.
- If the current thread's stack is too deep, then the task is queued elsewhere. (This is only a heuristic, and not guaranteed to avoid `StackOverflowException`).

That's quite a few conditions, but with your simple Console app test, they're all met:

- `TaskCompletionSource<T>` does not specify `RunContinuationsAsynchronously`.
- The continuation (`await`) does specify `ExecuteSynchronously`.
- The continuation does not have a `TaskScheduler` specified.
- The target thread is able to execute the continuation (not being aborted; stack is ok).

As a general rule, I would say any usage of `TaskCompletionSource<T>` should specify `TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously`. Personally, I think the semantics are more appropriate and less surprising with that flag.

Comment: I know that this is an old post, but just 2 questions to make things clear if anyone sees this: 1. Do most of the implementation details mentioned still apply in the .NET 5+ world today? 2. I assume the semantics for the `TrySet*` versions are the same as `Set*` if the try succeeds?

Comment: @scharnyw: yes and yes.